# html agility pack - Select specific node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I need to select node which has a specific value:

```
<td class='formlabel'>Name:</td>
```

So I have something like this:

```
HtmlNode selectedNote = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='formlabel'][starts-with(., 'Name:')]");
```

This works. But the problem is that this is a selection with starts-with so for example if I have code like this:

```
<td class='formlabel'>Name: some text</td>
```

It will also select the node. I need something that will select node only if this exists

```
<td class='formlabel'>Name:</td>
```

So it will select node which has only innerText equals "Name:"

Hmm...Is this possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
HtmlNode selectedNote = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='formlabel'][text()='Name:']");
```

Or

```
HtmlNode selectedNote = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='formlabel'][.='Name:']");
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you but how will look like whole code:

HtmlNode selectedNote = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='formlabel'][text()='Name:']"); Hmm.. Thank you